# Is there an industry term for a ribbon wrapping the corner of a design element?

Tags: terminology

Is there an industry term for a ribbon wrapping the corner of a design element?  I'm going to be referring to this a lot in the near future, and it would be great if I could call it something more intelligent than "The corner ribbon thingy"

One example of what I'm talking about is on the site: http://www.brasseriegerard.co.uk/
The right-hand div has three elements which it rotates through.  The first element has a red 'New' ribbon wrapping the corner of it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard it called a "snipe" by someone with 30 years in the advertising business. We also called it a "corner hat."

Answer (score 3):

I'd call it a 'corner flash'. It's often a triangle rather than a ribbon, and as in this case, it's most commonly associated with a "New!" message.

Comment: +1 for the only answer which, when put into google images, shows me what the questioner was referring to (their site seems to be currently down)

Comment: The company is permanently down AFAIK...

Answer (score 2):

I would probably call it a "corner element."