# What is the graphic design term for this element on a layout?

Tags: terminology, layout

Whether print or digital media, what is the name of this element?

On the main page layout, there is a small, not too obtrusive element with text inside. Usually a circle. It's not a callout because it's not referring to anything specifically on the main layout.

Here are two examples. See top right hand corner.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related, not identical: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/702/is-there-an-industry-term-for-a-ribbon-wrapping-the-corner-of-a-design-element/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Callout is what I generally refer to them as. A call out doesn't necessarily have to be literal. It can "call out to the viewer" not merely "call existing content to the foreground".

Clients can refer to them as "badges" or "seals" or "bursts".

In terms of design, then can also be referred to as "bastards" or "bastard elements" at times. By nature they are meant to be different than the rest of the design to call attention to themselves.

Comment: "Badges" or "stickers", especially in physical packaging.

Answer (score 6):

I've not come across a standard term for these. They've been variously referred to as "splash," "screech" and "decal" in conversation with different designers over the years.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Namely that there is no standard. :) I've also heard the term 'bug' used for these.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

The term might be dependent on the use.

If it was on a certificate, it would be termed a "seal" as a a gold foil stamp or notarized type circle to validate the document.

Otherwise I've termed it a "sticker" or sometimes a "burst" (like a sun with ray edges).

---

Answer (score 2):

When these are used on products in supermarkets, these are referred to 'flashes'.

For example, a product has a small sticker (a promotional flash) saying '2 for £3'.

Answer (score 1):

Callout. Or burst. Or bubble. Really, a callout.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, you received a downvote, most likely because Scott has answered the exact same thing about an hour before :)